# Having difficulty reading holding registers with pymodbus

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

Having difficulty reading holding registers with pymodbus

I'm trying to interface with a cheap benchtop power supply, just running some initial scripts to discern functionality. The OEM provided documentation on their modbus including [register addresses here](https://github.com/joeyda3rd/hanmatek-power-supply/blob/main/Modbus.pdf)

I can't seem to read the registers using pymodbus with this simple script. Code and output below.

What am I doing wrong? How to better debug? I'm new to modbus.

```py
import time
from pymodbus.client import ModbusSerialClient
from pymodbus.exceptions import ModbusIOException

def run():
        print("Creating client")
        client = ModbusSerialClient("/dev/ttyUSB0", method='rtu', baudrate=9600, stopbits=1, parity='N', bytesize=8, timeout=1)

        print("Connecting to client")
        if not client.connect():
                print("Failed to connect to client")
                return

        # List of register addresses to read from
        register_addresses = [0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0003, 0x0004, 0x0005, 0x0010, 0x0011, 0x0012, 0x0013, 0x0030, 0x0031, 0x0020, 0x0021, 0x0022, 0x0023, 0x9999]

        # Read from each register
        for address in register_addresses:
                try:
                        response = client.read_holding_registers(address, 1)
                        if response.isError():
                                print(f"Error reading register {address}: {response}")
                        else:
                                print(f"Register {address}: {response.registers}")
                        time.sleep(0.035)
                except ModbusIOException as e:
                        print(f"Modbus IO Exception reading register {address}: {e}")

        print("Closing client")
        client.close()

run()
```

When I run the previous code I get the following output:

```bash
└─$ python3 modbus4.py
Creating client
Connecting to client
Error reading register 1: Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] No response received, expected at least 4 bytes (0 received)
Error reading register 2: Modbus Error: [Input/Output] No Response received from the remote slave/Unable to decode response
...
Error reading register 39321: Modbus Error: [Input/Output] No Response received from the remote slave/Unable to decode response
```

Comment: What happens if you just pass int addresses as indexes for the registers? It's been a while since I played with modbus, but I'm sure I just used integers

Comment: @roganjosh actually, Python implicitly converts those hex digits to ints (try putting 0x20 into REPL, you'll get 32 out).

Comment: @NickS. learn something new every day (I feel I knew this, but apparently not). In any case, looking over the question again, I guess it's a connection error

Comment: @roganjosh no worries, I don't use Python every day, so didn't remember that off the top of my head either and simply checked. It's a good comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the server/slave ID explicitly in the read_holding_registers command, since you did not do it when initializing the client.

Try `response = client.read_holding_registers(address, count = 1, slave = 1)` and see if it replies.

I'm not 100% sure the server address is `1` though, so you might have to add another for-loop to iterate thru those as well; or dig a bit deeper into the manual, it should have it.

Comment: @roganjosh no, then he'd see a print-out of "Failed to connect to client". If you check some of the other posts, getting these types of errors is common due to using different argument names, not providing some arguments that are essential (in this case, the server address), and so on.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks!